# Cannon ip2700 driver problem

Tags: drivers, printing

I am attempting to get the cannon ip 2700 printer driver installed Ubuntu  20.04 1 LTS. This is a clean install replacing  windows 10 on a new Asus i5 system.

Currently not having any luck finding Linux compatible drivers.

Anyone gone through this problem and knows a source of the driver?

How do I get this printer working?

Thanks for your help
Bee Happy
Shanta

Comment: Is [the official driver](https://asia.canon/en/support/0100272002) not working for you?

Comment: Hi Matogo Thanks for the link. Failed to install missing dependencies.cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.4-1). lower version installed
 cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libcupsys2 (>= 1.2.1) | libcups2. not available 
 cnijfilter-common:i386 depends on libpopt0 (>= 1.7). lower version installed

Comment: The dependencies called for are a part of the current development release of Ubuntu. I am concerned that installing them will break the LTS installed.